# (Excel) How to combine two bar graphs, one with standard y-axis, other with inverted

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two bar graphs, one bar graph represents the mean plant (above soil) lengths (fall and spring) and the other represents the mean root length.

I have inverted the y-axis on the mean root length bar graph so that visually it appears like roots do, that is, going down.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJnvo.jpg

I wanted to know if it is possible to create one chart (in excel) in which these two are essentially merged, i.e. the bottom of the upper bars (upper chart) touch the top of the lower bars (lower chart).

This would be for aesthetic purposes only so that the data would better represent the plants/roots.

Answer (score 5):

Make a table listing root lengths and plant height, making sure root lengths are negative numbers.

Insert a stacked column chart, you should get something like this:

[image]

To answer @user41728's comment:

Right click on the label and select `Format Axis`, then select `Low` as the Label position:

[image]

Comment: In your solution above, is there a way to label the bars at the bottom, as is usually done in a bar chart?